# Git bash is showing "No such file or directory" when I try to cd into my documents or desktop

Tags: git-bash

Git bash is not showing all of my directories on my computer. It shows the directories in my Onedrive but I do not want to store my code there. How do I get all of the directories to show in my Git bash?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots what do you see, and what don't you see?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows make sure the file path you are `cd` into is the correct full path of where your project folder is i.e `C:/Users/admin/Documents/YourProject`